# About C++ types, and vectors

Tags: c++, oop, vector, subclassing

Let's say I have a few classes

Class Alpha (Base Class)

Class Beta (Subclass Alpha)

Class Delta (Subclass Alpha)

Would it be possible to create a `vector<Alpha>` and store object instances of types Alpha, Beta, and Delta all within that vector, and have the vector function as normal?

If not, supposing I wanted to have some sort of functionality like that, what would be the best approach?

Comment: If you used base class pointers/smart pointers, then yes. The big worry if you were storing value-objects (as opposed to pointer-to-objects) is object slicing (and maybe unexpected behavior if you have `virtual` methods and such).

Comment: Do you want the elements to behave differently based on whether they're `Alpha`s, `Beta`s or `Delta`s? Or do you want them to all act like `Alpha`s while they're in the `vector`? (Can't imagine a use for the second, but maybe you want it.)

Comment: They need to behave like Beta's and Delta's, and they will have some common method names that need be executed. Seth's virtual method declaration sounds very close to what I need. As long as the virtual method call can peer into the actual objects properties then I will be set.

Comment: Then you really do want to use `virtual` methods in your classes, and then use pointers-to-base class (or smart pointers, preferably), and store those in your vector. The `virtual` methods of each class will have access to the member fields of the class it belongs to (but will only have access to `public` and `protected` members of the parent).

Comment: @Jasconius - I figured as much. Seth's version is what you need, though if you want to avoid memory management you can use smart pointers as suggested by Ethan. And yes, virtual methods can do anything that regular methods can do. The _only_ difference is that in `Alpha *a = new Beta; a->method()`, if `method` was regular it would call `Alpha::method`, but if it was virtual it would call `Beta::method`. (It's a lot more expensive to do, so not all methods should be virtual, but it's C++ - you only pay for what you need.)

Comment: may be you can keep the pointer to those classes in a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to this is to have a vector full of pointers, and have the functions that are common to each of them be `virtual` in the base class:

```
class Alpha {
public:
    virtual void dosomething() { /* do something as an alpha */ }
};

class Beta : public Alpha {
public:
    void dosomething() { /* do something as a beta */ }
};

class Delta : public Alpha {
public:
    void dosomething() { /* do something as a delta */ }
};

vector<Alpha*> v;
v.push_back(new Alpha);
v.push_back(new Beta);
v.push_back(new Delta);

v[1]->dosomething(); // calls Beta's dosomething
```

You have to be careful with this approach however, to make sure and `delete` everything you `new` to put into the container. You could use smart pointers and avoid this caveat though:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Alpha> > v;
v.push_back(shared_ptr<Alpha>(new Alpha));
v.push_back(shared_ptr<Alpha>(new Beta));
v.push_back(shared_ptr<Alpha>(new Delta));

v[1]->dosomething(); // still calls Beta's dosomething
```

The reason you don't want to have a vector of `Alpha`s (instead of `Alpha*`s, which are alright) is because STL containers copy the values you give them, and if you copy a `Beta` (or `Delta`) as an `Alpha`, only `Alpha`'s copy constructor will be called and the resulting information will have to fit into the size of an `Alpha` (which if you've added any information to the subclass it won't be big enough), and the extra information the `Beta` (or `Delta`) had is lost. This is called slicing.

Comment: When I tried vector<Alpha*> objects; in my interface, Netbeans tells me "Unable to resolve identifier vector" ... thoughts?

Comment: @Jasconius make sure you `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;` or `using std::vector;` before you try using `vector`.

Comment: Oops, good call... weird that it wasn't asking for that beforehand... must have been some wizardry. OK, all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to store smart pointers to the classes in the vector.

You cannot pass by value, as you then get slicing.

If you pass by reference, you could have variables going out of scope.

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Alpha> > blah;
```